# Combine users from database to authorization role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I found example on internet

**Example:**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
return View();
}
```

I have Users table on my database and it has user names.

If my users have "Admin" Role, I want them to reach Index actionresult otherwise no.

**How can I combine my all  users to Admin Role?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution if you download article you can do it
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need a RoleProvider for that. There's a default [`SqlRoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx) that you could use and which would allow you to assign roles to your users.

Comment: can you give me simple example please  i can help you about points

Comment: The documentation I have linked to contains an example of how to register and configure the provider.

Comment: i have seen it but there is no sql data query for users.

Comment: What SQL data query are you talking about and why do you need that? You have to assign roles to your existing users in the corresponding SQL table.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs

here they add role and configure Using the Web Site Administration Tool.But i did not find it.